# Json array into select box with php

Tags: javascript, php, json, jquery-selectbox

I hope someone can help me with this issue I have. What I want is a select box, which is getting filled from a json file. The problem is I have a strange kind of json file which I dont know if its array or object.

Here is how it loosk like:

```
{
"Id": 4,
"Name": "Testing Demo",
"OpeningHours": [
    {
        "Name": "Monday",
        "Hours": "Kl. 09:30:00 - 21:00:00"
    }
],
"Address": {
    "Street": "Johnson road",
    "StreetNumber": "5",
    "Town": "London"
},
"Phone1": "4123213414",
"Phone2": null,
"Documents": null,
"Messages": [
    {
        "Title": "We are on the way",
        "Body": "fine",
        "Created": "01-02-2014"
    },
    {
        "Title": "Get the stuff",
        "Body": "To be ready",
        "Created": "01-01-2014"
    }
],
"Employees": [
    {
        "Name": "John Hood",
        "Description": "officer",
        "ProfileImageUrl": "http://grfx.cstv.com/photos/schools/kty/sports/m-baskbl/auto_headshot/9265204.jpeg"
    },
    {
        "Name": "John hood 2",
        "Description": "athletic",
        "ProfileImageUrl": "http://grfx.cstv.com/photos/schools/kty/sports/m-baskbl/auto_headshot/9265204.jpeg"
    }
]
}
```

How Iam going to show values of ID and the name?

This code it doesnt work which I dont know if Iam doing it even correctly..

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<tr class="form-field form-required"></tr>').append(
        $('<th scope="row">New field</th>')
    ).append(
        $('<td></td>').append(
            $('<select id="release-list"></select>')
        ).append(
            $('<p>Explanation about your new field</p>')
        )
    ).insertAfter('#wpbody-content table tr:eq(2)');




});

 $.getJSON('../../cache/path.json', function(data) {
    var select = $('#release-list');
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
        $('<option/>').attr('value', val[key]["Id"]).html('value' + val[key]["Name"]).appendTo(select);
    });
    });

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: the `Id`? you don't need a loop. its `data.Id`. for employees its `data.Employees` then use `.each`, then `val.Name`

Comment: @Ghost would u please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the data from json to array using JSON.parse()

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/parse.php

Example:

```
var data = '{"first":[1,2,3],"second":[4,5,6]}';
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(jsonData.first[1]);
alert(jsonData.second);
```

Comment: how do I insert it to the select box?

Comment: if your data has multiple array. what you can do is after you convert it to json run it in a loop then append it in select. select.append("<option value='" + jsonData.Id + "'>" + jsonData.Name + "</option>");